# "Use of unresolved identifier" error with ResearchKit code

Tags: swift, researchkit, xcode9.4

I'm building an app using ResearchKit through the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and the following code continues to give the error message: `Use of unresolved identifier 'consentSectionType'` which is the current one. Since I didn't write the code, I'm not sure what's wrong with it, and I don't know how to fix it. This is the code:

```
public var ConsentDocument: ORKConsentDocument {

let consentDocument = ORKConsentDocument()
consentDocument.title = "Consent"

let _: [ORKConsentSectionType] = [
    .overview,
    .dataGathering,
    .privacy,
    .dataUse,
    .timeCommitment,
    .studySurvey,
    .studyTasks,
    .withdrawing
]
var consentSections: [ORKConsentSection] = consentSectionType.map { contentSectionType in
    let consentSection = ORKConsentSection(type: contentSectionType)
    consentSection.summary = "x."
    consentSection.content = "y."
    return consentSection
}

consentDocument.sections = consentSections
```

Occasionally Xcode will suggest that I change `consentSectionType.map` to `ORKConsentSection.map`, but that just brings another error message that says `Type 'ORKConsentSection.map' has no member map`. This seems to be a case specific problem, as answers to the other questions weren't helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
let _: [ORKConsentSectionType] = [
  .Overview,
  .DataGathering,
  .Privacy,
  .DataUse,
  .TimeCommitment,
  .StudySurvey,
  .StudyTasks,
  .Withdrawing
]
```

with

```
let consentSectionType: [ORKConsentSectionType] = [
  .Overview,
  .DataGathering,
  .Privacy,
  .DataUse,
  .TimeCommitment,
  .StudySurvey,
  .StudyTasks,
  .Withdrawing
]
```

Comment: the error message came back. still not sure what to do, but thank you!

Comment: if you mean this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift it's very old ,, you can read this https://www.appcoda.com/researchkit/

Comment: make it consentSectionType

Comment: I've been looking for an updated one and that one seems great. Thanks!